# Why I am getting compile time error while using realm.executeTransactionAsync() method?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I am developing an application where I have to use **realm** database but whenever I am using `realm.executeTransactionAsync()` method it will give compile time error saying:

> can not resolve method realm.executeTransactionAsync(Anonymous
>   io.realm.Realm.Transaction)...

[image]

Comment: show code have use realm of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your project gradle

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
```

and delete any Realm compile at your model gradle and add

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

then execute this command

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: rebuild the project, close the android studio and reopen it.

Comment: did you delete the old dependencies ?

Comment: No, I just follow whatever you said, but it gives the same CE.

Comment: delete the old ones

Comment: Got the solution dude, I just delete the   compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.83.0+'  dependency from gradle.